# What does #[pallet::compact] do?

Tags: pallet, frame, assets, macro

What does #[pallet::compact] do? [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/pallet_macros/attr.compact.html

```
Compact encoding for arguments can be achieved via #[pallet::compact].
The function must return a DispatchResultWithPostInfo or DispatchResult.
```

It can make the args size smaller when you send a tx.

Comment: When should you use or not use it?  What should be the guideline?

Answer (score 0):

Compact encoding for arguments can be achieved via #[pallet::compact].
The function must return a  DispatchResult. it is useful for getting the compact decode